# get intermediate results from z3opt

Tags: z3

solving a large optimization problem with z3, which is not likely to reach optimum in a reasonable amount of time. Any way that I can get intermediate solutions ? perhaps set an internal time-out so it gives me the best solution it found so far ? 
Thanks, 
Ofer

Answer (score 1):

You can interrupt Z3 from the API directly or by setting a timeout. From the text front-end you can interrupt it (CTRL^C) or set a timeout. It returns a range of upper/lower bound and model of the best bound found so far.

Comment: How can I do this in Java API?

Comment: 1. Is the printed model, upon interruption with ^c, guaranteed to satisfy the hard constraints ?
2. Note that with -T nothing gets printed (only 'Timeout'), and -t does not work at all in my experience (it immediately exists with errors: 
(error "line 1700 column 10: canceled")
(error "line 1701 column 10: model is not available")

Comment: in the comment above (which I cannot edit apparently) there was a mistake regarding "-t"; it should be in mili-seconds and hence if the value is large enough the result is fine.